# Summing travel times with large list in python3

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, counter

I have a very large list (~2GB) of recorded travel times between various locations. Between each location there are multiple values listed with some of them repeating like this:

```
Raw_Travel_Times=[('AB',2),('BC',5),('AB',8),('BC',10),('BC',7)]
```

I am trying to efficiently calculate the average travel time between each location, something like:

```
Ave_Travel_Times=[('AB',5),('BC',11)]
```

I figured using `Counter` would be the way to go, but the best solution I have come up with is much too slow:

```
# count how many times each Origin-Destination pair occurs
    Trips=dict(Counter(Travel_Times))

{'AB':2,'BC':3}

# total travel time for each Origin-Destination pair
    CTime=Counter(AB)
    for t in Raw_Travel_Times:
      CTime=CTime+Counter({t[0]:t[1]})

    for c in CTime:
       Link=c
       Total_Time=CTime[c]
       Num_Trips=Trips[c]
       Avetime=TotalTime/Num_Trips
       Ave_Travel_Times.append(Link,Avetime)
```

There has to be a more efficient way to do this, but I am clearly not able to see it. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: With huge and homogeneous data such as yours, it might be worth switching to numpy. You'd probably see huge performance improvements, depending on what you do with your data.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I would suggest `pandas` is better suited to this task.

Comment: @Denziloe agreed, I didn't read it all through when I first responded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defaultdict` is what you're probably after:

```
location_times = [('AB',2),('BC',5),('AB',8),('BC',10),('BC',7)]

from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean

dd = defaultdict(list)

for location, time in location_times:
    dd[location].append(time)

result = {location: mean(times) for location, times in dd.items()}
```

Alternatively you could look into learning the basics of the `pandas` library.

Answer (score 1):

You could try sorting your data once, and going over them once to compute the averages. This needs sorting (which is extra work) but avoids appending a million items to lists (which is very slow):

```
from itertools import groupby
from statistics import mean # thanks to @Denziloe

raw_times = [('AB',2),('BC',5),('AB',8),('BC',10),('BC',7)]

def pathgetter(tup):
    return tup[0] # essentially operator.itemgetter(0)

temp_times = sorted(raw_times,key=pathgetter)
avg_times = [(path,mean((item[1] for item in sublist)))
             for path,sublist in groupby(temp_times,pathgetter)]
```

Credits go to [@Denziloe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880848/5067311) for `statistics.mean` which I didn't know about.